# Почему не применяется display grid к button элементу?

Tags: css, css-grid

Тут не центрируется

```css
button {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  height: 11vw;
  width: 11vw;
  background-color: tomato;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

button::after,
button::before {
  content: "";
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  height: 2vw;
  width: 2vw;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

А тут центрируется

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  height: 11vw;
  width: 11vw;
  background-color: tomato;
  border: none;
}

div::after,
div::before {
  content: "";
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  height: 2vw;
  width: 2vw;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

С абсолютным позиционированием

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  height: 11vw;
  width: 11vw;
  background-color: tomato;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

button::after,
button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2vw;
  width: 2vw;
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  height: 11vw;
  width: 11vw;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: none;
}

div::after,
div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2vw;
  width: 2vw;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
<div></div>
```

С флексами и там и там нормально работает

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 11vw;
  width: 11vw;
  background-color: tomato;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

button::after,
button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2vw;
  width: 2vw;
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 11vw;
  width: 11vw;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: none;
}

div::after,
div::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2vw;
  width: 2vw;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
<div></div>
```

В чём дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то это [баг](https://github.com/rachelandrew/gridbugs#10-some-html-elements-cant-be-grid-containers) в хроме.

> В Chrome (и Safari 10) [fieldset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) элементы с [display: grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) не ведут себя как grid-контейнеры. При применении [display: grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) к **button** элементу - этот **button** элемент ведёт себя как grid-контейнер только в Firefox.

Comment: уже вроде пофиксили.